# Grunt-stubby and protractor task

Tags: gruntjs, cucumber, protractor, stubs, stub-data-generation

I use Grunt in my project with angular and node. For the tests i use cucumber + protractor + [grunt-stubby](https://github.com/h2non/grunt-stubby) here is my register task from Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'selenium_start',
    'clean:server',    
    'ngconstant:testing',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma',
    'stubby',
    'protractor',
    'selenium_stop',
  ]);
```

My problem is when protractor task run, stubbys task is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess - you need to make use of grunt-protractor-runner and grunt-protractor-webdriver and tell grunt and protractor on which port stubby is listening, for example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    ..
    // Grunt server settings
    connect: {
        stubby: {
            options: {
                ..
                port: 8001
                .. 
            }
        }
    },
    ..
    protractor: {
        ..
        stubby: {
            options: {
                ..
                args: {
                     baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8001'
                }
                ..
            }
        }
        ..
    }
    ..

});
..
grunt.registerTask('test', [    
    ..,
    'karma',
    'connect:stubby',
    'stubby',
    'protractor:stubby'
]);
..
```